# Hide Facebook Page event during creation

Tags: facebook-pages, facebook-events

I'm trying to create an event for a Facebook Page that I'm administering. However, as soon as I create it, it goes public.

I seem to remember that there used to be some way to create events as hidden, fine-tune everything (graphics, descriptions, etc), then, once the time is right, flip a switch to make it public and start inviting people.

The privacy icon is on the event page, but it's just stuck at being public and grayed out.

Anyone know of any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, this can only be done for Events created within the context of your ***personal*** account, where Facebook allows you to control various aspects of Privacy.

On the other hand, it cannot be done for Events created within the context of a Page, because Pages are inherently ***public*** entities, and thus items such as Events, Photos, or Posts cannot be make private to any degree.

Comment: Well, I didn't find a way to do it either - but in any case, the idea was more to be able to hide it during creation and finetuning until it is ready - and not to restrict the event to only a certain group of people. I think that especially for public, possibly professional, entities, putting up an event, even for a short time, where the graphics and description are not completely done, is far from optimal...

Comment: I understood from the start what you were asking and why. Moreover, I totally agree with you that the current situation is far from optimal.

Answer (score 0):

As of Feb 2015 (and apparently for at least 7 months prior to then), Private Events cannot be created on a Facebook page, according to [this answer](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=873593115989552) on Facebook's Help Center:

> At this time, making an event on your Business Page private is not an available feature. I would suggest providing that feedback to the product team through this form: https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/354963731183415/?ref=u2u
>
> Many of the product and feature changes we've introduced over time have been driven by feedback from people like you and I know the product teams appreciate direct feedback such as this.

Answer (score 0):

As of late August 2015, an overhaul to the interface of FB page events lets you add the image before going live. There is also the ability to make hosts out of other pages you admin (and friends)  prior to creation.

I agree that creating a draft event would be a nice feature.